# emit() property of undefined - EventEmitter / @Output issue

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I've got a parent component with a child component. I've got binding between parent to child ok, but appear to be missing a detail the other direction from child to parent that I assume is my ignorance since both angular4/typescript are new to me.

So the parent component hosts a child component and passes data to the child fine;

```
<app-component-name (onSomethingAdded)="doSomethingWithIt($event)"></app-component-name>
```

Where `<app-component-name>` happens to be a dialog child component with the intent that the user enters a string address that I geocode to Lat/Lng via google maps API. The dialog displays fine, the input is entered and returns fine, the geocoding goes through and my lat/lng is returned with no problem....my problem is getting that object with the coords etc back to the parent component where the map is so I can add a marker for it etc...

In the child component I declare my @Ouput like so;

```
@Output() 
 onSomethingAdded = new EventEmitter<{animation:any, title: string, position: {lat:number, lng:number}}>();
```

Then the method that's supposed to emit this bugger back to the parent component (which fires fine because it's also where I do the geocoding from the inputs in the Dialog child component) looks like this...

```
addNewSomething(newLoc) {

   // A bunch of other stuff omitted for the sake of a small example
   // THIS BUGGER below pukes at me
   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

        this.onSomethingAdded.emit({ 
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          title: newLoc.form.controls.title.value,
          position: {
            lat: res[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: res[0].geometry.location.lng()
          }
        });
}
```

Where `newLoc` is the object I get back from ngForm from the Dialog inputs and looks fine, and google maps returns me my coords and data just fine for the lat/lng as shown. So I'm hoping one of you folks at this longer can spot my folly out to me real quick as to why I get that undefined `emit` property? Did I just do something noob like forget to define something?

I know all the values I'm trying to emit are there, so I'm obviously missing some basic definition or something right? Thanks for the hand learning.

Comment: where are you calling this `addNewSomething` in your child component. You can take a look at [this](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) for a simplistic event emitters

Comment: @RahulSingh That method gets called from the form in the child component.html like; `<form name="newLoc" (ngSubmit)="addNewSomething(newLoc)"......` where newLoc is the ngForm object - I'll go check out the link you provided and see if I can't spot something obvious thanks :)

Comment: are all the properties undefined or only one ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Nah all the properties should be fine since I use the same properties to do other things within the child component and they're fine. I just can't seem to get that object back to the parent to so I can push it to the marker array on the parent component.

Comment: Make sure you imported Output and EventEmitter from core. Have you tried  initialising the output like this: @Output onSomethingAdded:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

Comment: @gyc Ya the imports are there, intellij is good about complaining that sort of thing. Also tried the alternate emitter syntax but still get the same `Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined` error.

Comment: try use this **this.onSomethingAdded.next()** instead of emit method

Comment: @Chandru that just changes the error to the same thing but with 'next' of undefined instead of 'emit' :/

Comment: Which modal dialog box are you using ngx-bootstrap or ng-bootstrap ?

Comment: @Chandru Using [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) as the child component dialog but the data is passed via default ngForm. The data from the dialog form gets back to the component just fine.....I still just don't understand why it's saying the emit() method is a property anyway? Hell honestly I thought this was just something easy I forgot but I guess not lol.

Comment: did you create plunker ?

Comment: It says the `emit()` method is a property, because technically, it *is*.

Comment: @BlueM Ah right on ya, wasn't thinking about prototyping at the time, lack of sleep at the time. Anyway I figured this out and will share a more detailed answer when I get a minute. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue turned out to be in the variable scope supplied by the nested methods. For other readers this was the fix in pseudo.

```
addNewSomething(newLoc) {

   const that = this;

   aChildMethod() {


      yetAnotherNestedMethod() {

        that.onSomethingAdded.emit({ 
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          title: newLoc.form.controls.title.value,
          position: {
            lat: res[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: res[0].geometry.location.lng()
          }
        });
      }
   }
};
```

Wherein the `that=this;` was the fix. Thanks for everyone trying to help. :)